# SQL: Select the largest value for a group

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a table like this:

| someOtherCols | shelf | type | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | row1 | A | 2 |
| ... | row1 | B | 3 |
| ... | row2 | C | 2 |
| ... | row2 | D | 2 |

I would like to group by shelf, and only keep the type that has the highest count. If there's a tie, choose any row.

So the result would be like:

| someOtherCols | shelf | type | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | row1 | B | 3 |
| ... | row2 | C | 2 |

I'm using AWS Athena and I'm trying the following query that I saw from another answer I saw:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE count IN (MAX(count) FROM shoppingAggregate GROUP BY someOtherCols, shelf)
```

Seems like Athena does not like it. How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

you will have to do an over for each attribute in "some other cols". I used min below (you have to make the query deterministic). You can choose what you prefer.

```
select distinct -- you need to remove duplicates
           min(othercol) over (partition by row), 
           row, max(type) over (partition by row), 
           count(*) over (partition by row)
   from relation;
```

sqlite will allow you to have a non-determinist query that will be significantly simpler using a group by (but it will not work in other dbms)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use ROW_NUMBER() and was able to solve this problem:

```
ranked AS (
  SELECT table.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY othercols, shelf ORDER BY counts DESC) AS rn
  FROM table
)
SELECT * FROM ranked WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Presto offers the function `max_by()` which I think is in Athena as well:

```
select shelf, max(count), max_by(type, count)
from t
group by shelf
```